# Concatenate pandas dataframes with varying rows per index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 with `key` as index.

```
dict_1={'key':[1,1,1,2,2,3], 'col1':['a1','b1','c1','d1','e1','f1']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1).set_index('key')
dict_2={'key':[1,1,2], 'col2':['a2','b2','c2']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2).set_index('key')
```

df1:

```
       col1
key
1       a1
1       b1
1       c1
2       d1
2       e1
3       f1
```

df2

```
       col2
key 
1      a2
1      b2
2      c2
```

Note that there are unequal rows for each index. I want to concatenate these two dataframes such that, I have the following dataframe (say df3).

df3

```
       col1 col2
key 
1       a1   a2
1       b1   b2
2       d1   c2
```

i.e. concatenate the two columns so that the new dataframe as the least (of df1 and df2) rows for each index.

I tried

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Value Error: Shape of passed values is (2,17), indices imply (2,7)
```

My question: How can I concatentate `df1` and `df2` to get `df3`? Should I use `DataFrame.merge` instead? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge/join alone will get you a lot of (hard to get rid of) duplicates. But a little trick will help:

```
df1['count1'] = 1
df1['count1'] = df1['count1'].groupby(df1.index).cumsum()
df1
Out[198]: 
    col1  count1
key             
1     a1       1
1     b1       2
1     c1       3
2     d1       1
2     e1       2
3     f1       1
```

The same thing for `df2`:

```
df2['count2'] = 1
df2['count2'] = df2['count2'].groupby(df2.index).cumsum()
```

And finally:

```
df_aligned = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), left_on = ['key','count1'], right_on = ['key', 'count2'])
df_aligned
Out[199]: 
   key col1  count1 col2  count2
0    1   a1       1   a2       1
1    1   b1       2   b2       2
2    2   d1       1   c2       1
```

Now, you can reset index with `set_index('key')` and drop no longer needed columns `countn`.

Comment: Thanks for the 'little trick'. That's the missing link that I couldn't comprehend. I accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Bhushan Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem for why you are not going to be able to line up the two in the way that you want is that your keys are duplicative. How are you going to be line up the A1 value in `df1` with the A2 value in `df2` When A1, A2, B1, B2, and C1 all have the same key?

Using [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is what you'll want if you can resolve the key issues:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

You can use `inner`, `outer`, `left` or `right` for `how`.

Comment: duplicative keys is part of the dataframe. Here is the larger context: 'id1' is the index of a buffer id [say: 0 to 255], and 'col1' and 'col2' are timestamps when the buffer is acquired and released. buffers are going to be acquired/released over a large time window and ptrj's answer helped me reorder the dataframe such that i can calculate the time duration in which a buffer is in use.